# navigating site programmatically

Tags: navigation

I am currently working on a project for which i have to navigate site programmatically. I am using C#. In some case sites navigates(change contents of page) on the event of a control, while URL remain same. like the one below

http://www.centurysecuritiesng.com/Home/tabid/36/ctl/listing/mid/410/Default.aspx

On this page there is a dropdown(Price List as at)  and the content of the page changes on dropdown item change, while URL of the page remain same. can anybody suggest that how can i achieve this programmatically, mean changing dropdown item dynamically and getting its content against that dropdown item.

In short i want dynamic content of the page which is coming against event of a control, based on some value. Which in my case is onchange event of dropdrown based on selected value of the dropdown

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're scraping a third party's Web site, you should check their terms of use, and perhaps consult with a lawyer, to make sure what you're doing is legal. This is factual information, and the site doesn't appear to have terms of use that forbid scraping, so you may be OK, but IANAL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Selenium. Take a look at: http://seleniumhq.org/. Also, you can write web crawler in many languages of your choice. If you prefer .NET, take a look at HttpWebRequestClass.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question, but I assume you're trying to make your C# app automate a Web browser that's running as a separate application (as opposed to embedding a WebBrowser control in your app and automating that).

This sounds like the sort of thing [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) is meant to automate. It's intended for automated tests (which may or may not be what you're doing) but gives you an easy way to drive an external instance of either IE or FireFox, navigate to pages, find text fields and type into them, click buttons, etc.

A sample code snippet from their site:

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
}
```

Comment: In short i want dynamic content of the page which is coming against event of a control, based on some value. which in my case is onchange event of dropdrown based on selected value of the dropdown

Comment: I am writing a web scrapper and for that i want dynamic content of that page. am i clear now?

Comment: Initially, from OP's description, I thought the site used AJAX, so something like WatiN would be useful (since it loads the site in a browser and actually runs all the JavaScript). However, I looked at the site OP linked to, and it actually does a postback -- and that can be easily simulated with HTTP calls with something like the HTML Agility Pack, which should be faster than out-of-process automation. So while I think WatiN would work, it may not be the best solution for this particular problem.

Comment: @Jeo thanks for all your helpful replays, i think i am very close to the solution. if you look into the source on this page you will find this:
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'dnn$ctr410$listing$priceDateList\',\'\')', 0)"


now if i use HTTPWebRequest object to get content, what should i give in postback data?

Comment: That depends on what the page's __doPostBack method does. The easiest thing is probably to use a tool like Firebug or Fiddler to see what actual data is being posted. I can't help you there, never having used either for anything like this -- so if you have trouble figuring it out, it's probably worth posting a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do page scraping. If yes then [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is best choice for you to use in your .NET application and scrap the page programmatically.